# AngularJS установить элементу класс, если он скрыт за границами другого блока

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть у меня блок, внутри которого элементы выводятся в `ng-repeat`. Если элемент (`class="item"`) частично или полностью (при склоре блока) выходит за его границы, этому элементу мне нужно установить класс например "`novisible`".

Еще раз, что мне нужно. Пользователь прокручивает родительский блок, все дочерние элементы (`div class="item"`), которые за границей видимости, должны получить класс "`novisible`".

```css
.item {
height:30px;
border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid; overflow: auto;">
  
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
      <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
      <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: сформулируйте, пожалуйста, сам вопрос, на который вам могли бы ответить. и добавьте его в текст, нажав [edit].

Comment: поправил. Думаю, теперь понятно.

Comment: Это бесполезно.

Answer (score 2):

Оборачивайте весь блок в директиву, а далее работайте с DOM и её `event`'ами (`scroll`) + `addClass/removeClass` (`ng-class`, если больше нравится).

При первом старте, чтобы дождаться когда `ng-repeat` отработает, можно использовать решение наподобие такого:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished

Comment: дождаться, когда ng-repeat отработает не проблема, проблема получить координаты каждого элемента ng-repeat на странице. Если бы я знал координаты каждого элемента, я бы сделал условие, если до верха окна менее 100 пикселей - установить класс и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var Model = (function(){
var allItems = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
 allItems.push({name: 'item-' + i });
}

return {
 getAllItems: function(){
  return allItems;
 }
};
})();

var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('ItemController', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.model = Model.getAllItems();
}]);

app.directive('customScroll', ['$injector', function(){
// Runs during compile
return {
 link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
  var dataCollection = $scope[iAttrs['customScroll']];
  var length = dataCollection.length;
  var element;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
   element = angular.element('<div class="item">' + dataCollection[i].name + '</div>');
   iElm.append(element);
  }

  // а вот теперь делайте все так же, как я показал Вам раньше.
  // Но если со временем появятся ошибки при скроле, то напишите о них,
  // мне самому интересно.
  
  iElm[0].addEventListener('scroll', iElem_scrollHandler);

  function iElem_scrollHandler(event){
   var allChildren = event.target.children;
   var length = allChildren.length;
   var item;

   for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
    item = allChildren[i];

    if(item.getBoundingClientRect().y > 0){
     if(false /*что-то тут*/){
      /*что-то делаем*/
     }else{
      break;
     }
    }

    /*оффаем*/
   }
  }
 }
};
}]);
```

```css
.item {
 height:30px;
 border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="ItemController">
  <div custom-scroll="model" id="scroll-container" style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid; overflow: auto;"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Все отлично, только можно как то это в директиву ангуляра завернуть?